# Behavior of a person towards 'others' or 'to other people'. Which is correct?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Our instructor ask us a question about what attitude is and I recited with this answer, "behavior of a person towards others" but she add some words when she write it on whiteboard, "others" to "to other people". Is my sentence valid or lack of some words as what my instructor does?

I'm not really good at English, and it's my first time to ask question here. Please help me, thank you.

Comment: If your instructor truly wrote "behavior of a person towards to other people" or "behavior of a person to other people" then she made the sentence worse, but "...towards other people" would be valid as noted in the accepted answer

Comment: @KamilDrakari Yes, I also thought about that because my sentence was simple or short, why she need to make it long but I think she just want the sentence to more specific maybe that's why she added "to other people". Anyway thanks for the respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both sentences are correct, the first one is more common, the second is slightly softer.

Comment: Thank very much. I can now rest. I was very insecure not knowing if I did it right or wrong because I said it in front of my classmate and I stuttered. Really, thank you.